# Spreadsheetlight: Border around cell range, no internal borders

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

Using SpreadsheetLight I want to add a border (only) around a cell range. There shouldn't be any borders inside that range.

What I want:

[image: What I want]

What I get:

[image]

Code I used:

```
var testDoc = new SLDocument();

var testStyle = testDoc.CreateStyle();
testStyle.Border.Outline = true;
testStyle.Border.SetLeftBorder(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thin, Color.Black);
testStyle.Border.SetRightBorder(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thin, Color.Black);
testStyle.Border.SetTopBorder(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thin, Color.Black);
testStyle.Border.SetBottomBorder(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thin, Color.Black);
testDoc.SetCellStyle("A3", "F5", testStyle);

return testDoc;
```

What am I doing wrong? I expected the option Border.Outline = true to result in only producing an outline. Setting it to false doesn't change anything in the output.
I'm using SpreadsheetLight in the version 3.5.0 (most current version on NuGet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix the problem with the styles, but I found another option to draw borders, and this one actually draws an outline like I wanted. Maybe this helps others having the same problem:

```
testDoc.DrawBorder("A3", "F5", DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.BorderStyleValues.Thin, Color.Black);
```